# Extracting skatepark data as JSON file

Tags: qgis, geojson, query, overpass-turbo, quickosm

I am new to QGIS but I need to create a JSON file with skatepark name and lat long.

I have tried to use [quickOSM plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickOSM/) for QGIS with the tag `leisure=pitch` and `sport=skateboard` but it ends up giving me all parks, when i need skateparks only.  Some are labeled `"extreme sports area"` or `"skatepark"`.

How do I make a query that could solve this problem?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you are using some public available dataset? If so, can you give us a link - then it may be easier to help you. If not - can you post a couple of examples of features you did and did not expect to get from the query?

Comment: babel advice worked, using overpass gave me the results i needed, strangely not quickOSM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Overpass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) web interface, zoom to your region of interest, click `Wizard` and enter this string: `sport:skate or sport:extreme`.

Using double points `:` instead of equal symbol `=`, it uses wildcards (thus finding variants like skate or skateboard). The wizard automatically converts the string to a valid overpass query when you click create and run query.

You can directly export the results als JSON file by clicking `Export` on the upper left.

[image]

Comment: this gave me a good result, thank you! also, i tried using this query in quickOSM, and it did not give me the same results, showing skateboard shops and not parks. Thats something i need to filter out. Also, when using quickOSM i have an option to uncheck multipolygons. Is there a way to have the results show points only instead of polygons in overpass turbo?

Comment: See on the left side of the screenshot: you have in fact three queries: for nodes (points), ways (lines) and relations. You could just run it for nodes. Or even better (as I'm not 100% sure that results will be the same) download all, open in QGIS and just save the point layer and discard the other ones.

Comment: this works. many thanks.